# columns disappear after groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the below df:

```
data0 = {
    'state':  ['CA', 'CA', 'OH'],
    'year':   [2012, 2014, 2010],
    's': [2000, 4000, 5000]
     }
data1=pd.DataFrame(data0)
```

When I do the count:

```
data2=data1.groupby(['state'])['s'].agg({'result': 'count'})
```

I get the correct results and I can display both 'state' and 'result'. But the state column disappears. So if I run:

```
data2.columns
```

It returns:

```
Index(['result'], dtype='object')
```

It also fails if I try to join data2 with another df on state column because state is not found in data2.

Not understanding why this is happening!

Answer (score 1):

Although `data2.columns` show that the `state` column is missing, the `state` column would actually be included in the dataframe as the **index** of the dataframe.

```
data2=data1.groupby(['state'])['s'].agg({'result': 'count'})
data2
```

```
      result
state   
CA        2
OH        1
```

[EDIT] Thanks to @sammywemmy

To make your `state` column to a column instead of the index for your column-wise join, you could simply:

```
data2=data1.groupby(['state'], as_index=False)['s'].agg({'result': 'count'})
data2
```

```
    state   result
0      CA       2
1      OH       1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch wookiekim! any idea how to make it show as state instead so I can use the column in joins with other dfs?

Comment: try data1.groupby(['state'], as_index=False)

Comment: @sammywemmy thank you! May I make an edit to add that to my answer, citing you?